# Window handle debugging in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I have a user that keeps getting this error.  Is there a tool that does window handle counting that i can use to figure out why he keeps getting this error.

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error creating window handle.
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)

Comment: You need more information about this behaviour.
This problem can apear on several situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best counter I know is Taskmgr.exe.  View + Select Columns and check "User objects",  "Handle count" and "GDI Objects".

The generic diagnostic is that you're leaking handles and consumed 10,000 of them.  Beware of a handle leak bug in .NET 2.0 SP1 and .NET 3.5's Graphics.CopyFromScreen(), fixed in 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Do you have a link for the leak bug in .NET 2.0 SP1?

Comment: @eric - analysis is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/cedaa0f2-383c-4e61-92c0-c09123cb67cd/

Answer (score 2):

If the Form you are creating overrides WndProc(), be careful to ensure that it always calls base.WndProc() during the window creation process.

I inadvertently omitted a call to base.WndProc() in my override, and got your stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

[Unhandled exception Win32Exception,Error creating window handle](http://www.aboutmydot.net/index.php/unhandled-exception-win32exceptionerror-creating-window-handle)

[CLR Debugger (DbgCLR.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxbks7z(VS.80).aspx)

on mine machine debugger is located at:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\GuiDebug\DbgCLR.exe"
```

Comment: where can you download this from.. i dont seem to have it on my machine.

Comment: I am not sure. I got it with Visual Studio install. Maybe you should instal .NET SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en